# Un comportamiento inusual de position:bsolute; CSS "¿entienden esto?"

Tags: javascript, html, css3, css-transform

**El código hace que: cuando hagas hover en cada div de clase ".columnas" la imagen de fondo de su div padre cambiara.**
**----El problema es:** Cuando haces hover de izquierda a derecha todo correcto; pero cuando lo haces al revés, es como si las ".columnas" se hubieran desplazado hacia la izquierda.
**¿ Como hacer para que hover también funcione de derecha => izquierda?**

**NOTA1:** al ejecutar, esperen un poco para que las imagenes carguen, tome cualquier imagen :).

**NOTA2:** en el código aparece "**--backgroundImg**" es una variable css para cada ".columna" en su estilo en linea, de tal forma que cuando sucede hover se pondrá su respectivo valor.

```css
.skt-hero {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    background-image: url(https://haciendofotos.com/wp-content/uploads/las-mejores-fotos-de-paisajes-2020.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
.skt-hero:hover{
    background-image: none;
}
.columnas {
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.columnas:hover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: var(--backgroundImg);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="skt-hero"> <!--Inicia contenedor -->
<div class="columnas" style="--backgroundImg: url(https://cdn.thecoolist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Japanese-Cherry-beautiful-tree.jpg)">hola</div>
<div class="columnas" style="--backgroundImg: url(https://wallpaperstock.net/wonderful-trees-path-sun-light-wallpapers_47680_1920x1200.jpg)">hola</div>
<div class="columnas" style="--backgroundImg: url(https://img.culturacolectiva.com/featured_image/2018/10/04/1538678265674/deforestacion-del-bosque-amazonico-diecisiete-por-ciento.jpg)" >hola</div>
<div class="columnas" style="--backgroundImg: url(https://st.depositphotos.com/1012061/4434/i/600/depositphotos_44342021-stock-photo-sun-rays-inside-coconut-palms.jpg)">hola</div>
</div> <!-- Fin del contenedor -->
```

**NOTA3:** Seria bueno que sea puro CSS; pero si no hay opción, la forma javascrip también será genial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando el mouse toca un casillo, estás enlargando el casillo a ocupar todo del contenedor. El problema con este es que cuando mueves los casillos, los posiciónes de los casillos se cambian y el mouse toca otro casillo. Este causa otros casillos a tener el estado de `hover` y todo sucede una y otra vez.

Creo que el mejor solución cuando necesitas eventos en los elementos hijos a burbuejar hasta los padres sería usar oyentes de eventos en javascript.

```js
const sktHero = document.querySelector('.skt-hero');

sktHero.addEventListener('mouseover', e => sktHero.style.backgroundImage = e.target.getAttribute('data-backgroundImg'));
sktHero.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => sktHero.style.backgroundImage = '');
```

y para cada div use `data-backgroundImg` en vez de style

```html
<div class="columnas" data-backgroundImg="url(https://cdn.thecoolist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Japanese-Cherry-beautiful-tree.jpg)">hola</div>
```

---

Ejemplo:

```js
const sktHero = document.querySelector('.skt-hero');

sktHero.addEventListener('mouseover', e => sktHero.style.backgroundImage = e.target.getAttribute('data-backgroundImg'));
sktHero.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => sktHero.style.backgroundImage = '');
```

```css
.skt-hero {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    background-image: url(https://haciendofotos.com/wp-content/uploads/las-mejores-fotos-de-paisajes-2020.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
.columnas {
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="skt-hero"> <!--Inicia contenedor -->
<div class="columnas" data-backgroundImg="url(https://cdn.thecoolist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Japanese-Cherry-beautiful-tree.jpg)">hola</div>
<div class="columnas" data-backgroundImg="url(https://wallpaperstock.net/wonderful-trees-path-sun-light-wallpapers_47680_1920x1200.jpg)">hola</div>
<div class="columnas" data-backgroundImg="url(https://img.culturacolectiva.com/featured_image/2018/10/04/1538678265674/deforestacion-del-bosque-amazonico-diecisiete-por-ciento.jpg)" >hola</div>
<div class="columnas" data-backgroundImg="url(https://st.depositphotos.com/1012061/4434/i/600/depositphotos_44342021-stock-photo-sun-rays-inside-coconut-palms.jpg)">hola</div>
</div> <!-- Fin del contenedor -->
```

Comment: Gracias! por resolverlo, estoy mejorando en javascript y desconocia"data" en data-backgroundImg, así que tuve que hacerlo por css.  Gran aporte, marcare como respuesta tu pregunta............

Answer (score 2):

**Pensé que la propiedad Z-index era simple**; pero depende del anidamiento y otras cosas; tarde en entenderlo.
**La razón porque position:absolute; se comportaba** así, es que al ser absoluto sale del flujo normal, y se ubica en el origen de su contenedor, sobrando 3 "columnan" con display flex que se ubican en el origen del contenedor, ya que solo quedan 3 respetando el flujo.
**bueno, Aquí dejo la la solución con Css puro** para quien quiera verlo.

```css
body{
z-index: -10:
} /* para asegurar que nadie este por debajo de body*/
.skt-hero {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    background-image: url(https://haciendofotos.com/wp-content/uploads/las-mejores-fotos-de-paisajes-2020.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
.skt-hero:hover{
    z-index:-3;
    background-image:;
    position:;
}
.columnas {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: transparent;
    position:absolute;
}
.columnas:hover {
    height: 100%;
    width:100vw;
    background-image: var(--backgroundImg);
    position: ;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: cover;
}
.z1{} /*no hace falta*/
.z2{
left:25%;
}
.z2:hover{
left:0%;
}
.z3{
left:50%;
}
.z3:hover{
left:0%;
}
.z4{
left:75%;
}
.z4:hover{
left:0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="skt-hero"> <!--Inicia contenedor -->
<div class="columnas z1" style="--backgroundImg: url(https://cdn.thecoolist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Japanese-Cherry-beautiful-tree.jpg)">1ahola</div>
<div class="columnas z2" style="--backgroundImg: url(https://wallpaperstock.net/wonderful-trees-path-sun-light-wallpapers_47680_1920x1200.jpg)">2a</div>
<div class="columnas z3" style="--backgroundImg: url(https://img.culturacolectiva.com/featured_image/2018/10/04/1538678265674/deforestacion-del-bosque-amazonico-diecisiete-por-ciento.jpg)" >3a</div>
<div class="columnas z4" style="--backgroundImg: url(https://st.depositphotos.com/1012061/4434/i/600/depositphotos_44342021-stock-photo-sun-rays-inside-coconut-palms.jpg)">4a</div>
</div> <!-- Fin del contenedor -->
```

> La solución concite en sacar del flujo todos las ".columnas" y posicionarlo con left, 0%,25%,50%,75% y luego en el hover hacer que vuelvan a left:0%;